# android - return ignored in try-statement

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, disconnect, try-catch-finally

I have a class called `RetreiveHttpStringResponse`. It's used to get an `InputStream` from an URL containing JSON data. The class extends `AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>`. So the strange problem here is that null is always returned. No matter what. There is even no Exception. I checked out the program behaviour with the debugger and could see that at point (1) the processing is jumping immediately to the finally-statement and continues with `return null;`. And again there are no Errors and no Exceptions are going on. The programm is running normally.
I'm using Android 4.4 (SDK version 19), the response code is 200 and the following lines are set in the Manifest file.

- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

The problem is happening on the emulator and on a real device with internet connection. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    URL url = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    int responseCode = 0;

    try {
        url = new URL(arg0[0]);
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConn.connect();

        responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("DataHandlerInternet:RESPONSE_CODE", "The response is: " + responseCode);

        is= urlConn.getInputStream(); //-->(1)<--
        return is;
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException e ) { // new URL() went wrong!
        //TODO error message. URL is not correct!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) { // Timeout while connecting or holding connection to URL.
        //TODO error message. Timeout happened!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) { // openConnection() failed!
        //TODO error message. Couldn't connect to URL!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) { // Any other Exception!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { if(is != null) { is.close(); } } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try { if(urlConn != null) { urlConn.disconnect(); } } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    return null;
}
```

One bad solution is to delete the finally-statement. Well, not the best way to solve this problem.
Now I changed the code. I've put the reading in it and return just the String.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    URL url = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    int responseCode = 0;

    try {
        url = new URL(arg0[0]);
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConn.connect();

        responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("DataHandlerInternet:RESPONSE_CODE", "The response is: " + responseCode);

        is= urlConn.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while (  (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException e ) { // new URL() went wrong!
        //TODO error message. URL is not correct!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) { // Timeout while connecting or holding connection to URL.
        //TODO error message. Timeout happened!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) { // openConnection() failed!
        //TODO error message. Couldn't connect to URL!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) { // Any other Exception!
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { if(is != null) { is.close(); } } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        try { if(urlConn != null) { urlConn.disconnect(); } } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    return null;
}
```

And still, after going through the while loop the `return line;` is completely ignored. I've checked the data in the String with the debugger and it was correct! No Errors no Exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure that in the input stream is something to get? To get not null you can simply initialize your
is = new InputStream(); and then assign to your 'is' variable[firstly initialized] only when ulrConn.getInputStream()!=null :)

Comment: The problem is that the programm is jumping to return null; and ignores return is; completely. Even if is has no inputstream it is still not returned.

Comment: It can't do it, or simply you get an exception and not catch it in any catch clause in your code. But it also can not jump to 'return null' line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see why you get your null result but, one thing you are doing wrong is actually returning `InputStream`:

```
    is= urlConn.getInputStream(); //-->(1)<--
    return is;
```

you should read your stream in `doInBackground` (on worker thread), otherwise reading it in onPostExecute (UI Thread), will possibly cause `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, or at least ANR. Reading data from InputStream is still a network operation - data you download can be several MBs.

Comment: Thanks, but the reading is done in the doInBackround Method. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: from your code I dont see you have read anything from your InputStream

Comment: also, you are returning InputStream but also closing it in finally (read Audrius Meškauskas answer), so you will get closed InputStream in onPostExecute.

Comment: change to return sb.toString();

Comment: yeah right, thanks. my mistake. now it's working. That means that I have to read the inputstream inside the AsyncTask. Still confusing the behaviuor I got before. The return statement was completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` will run in either case, also during normal return without exceptions. And you call .`close` in the `finally` statement clause.

So your code always returns the closed stream. Probably this is not that you intend.

Your description ("jumps to finally statement") still looks very much like a exception has been thrown by `urlConn.getInputStream()`. Strange you do not observe it.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that about finally but do you mean I shouldn't close my inputstream? And yes I couldn't see any Exceptions. The rest of the programm is still going on.

Comment: You now have edited the code to return string rather than input stream so this is no longer relevant.